# Is it possible to force LaTex to put fonts into the pdf output?

Tags: fonts, pdf, printing, embedding

Sometimes when I make a document with Hungarian letters, the pdf is perfect on the screen, but my printer cannot handle the Hungarian letters. I don't know where is the source of the problem (in the pdf file, with the driver of my printer, or with the installed fonts) but I would like to ask the following: is it possible to force LaTeX compiler to put the fonts into the pdf file?

Comment: The fonts *are* embedded in the PDF. Only the needed glyphs, in general, but this should make no problem.

Comment: I have occasionally had printing issues (though not with foreign text) which I have been able to correct.  I have found that, for windows systems, if you you go to your printer preferences, advanced printing properties, there are many parameters to explore that might help (e.g., send TrueType as Bitmap T/F, Send Graphics as Vector/Rastor; TrueType Font "Substitute with Device Font"/"Download as Soft Font", etc.)  Some of these options are no doubt printer specific, but it is something you should check.

Comment: Perhaps you should try to compile with `xelatex'.

Comment: Run the file through pdf2ps and then back through ps2pdf if you are on a suitable system. (Any Unix-based system - not sure about Windows.) This often solves printing problems for me even with the crappy print drivers in the photocopiers at work. (Our printers are fine but don't do colour. Hence the need to use a photocopier to print.) On my system, the resulting PDF actually shows as having **no** fonts. Then it usually works. (File will be large, though.)